# Very strange matlab behaviour

Tags: matlab

I have matlab in version R2014b (64bit) on computer that runs windows 8. when I enter "float" or "boolean" to the command window, all matlab windows get resized and the gui-elements and fonts are all suddenly way smaller. It doesn't really prevent me from working, but it's just a really strange bug. A friend of mine tried it on ubuntu (I don't know whether the matlab version was the same) and it did not occur. Can anyone confirm that I'm not the only one having this issue?

Comment: i'm running 2014b 64bit on win7 and ubuntu, but what you said does not happen

Comment: Is this on a high DPI display?

Comment: It's on my Microsoft Surface 3.